# Can't lock vz with proxmox

Tags: virtualization, virtual-machines, openvz, proxmox

I would like to backup my virtual servers to move them away. And when i have started the backup process then i only see this every time:

```
Feb 09 08:40:34 INFO: Starting Backup of VM 101 (openvz)
Feb 09 08:40:34 INFO: CTID 101 exist mounted running
Feb 09 08:40:34 INFO: status = running
Feb 09 08:41:34 ERROR: Backup of VM 101 failed - can't lock VM 101
```

If you need any more details then i will give them for you!
Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Is the vm stopped when you try to backup?

Comment: it isn't stopped but i've already tried to backup when the virtual server was stopped... the same error

Answer (score 1):

Lock files are stored here in `/var/lib/vz/lock/`. Any chance this directory is not writable/missing ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to unlock the VM with this: 
`qm unlock VMID`